# Greeting "Good Day" Formally

Tags: word-usage

What about formally greeting people on first meeting quite into the day, say post 11:30 AM through out the day? Though generally we are used to saying "Good morning" "Good afternoon" & so on, it has been observed, it gets somewhat difficult for a majority of the blue-collared employees with a mother tongue other than English, not allowed to wear watches, working in a hospital and who therefore mostly end up greeting incorrectly(considering the popular usage). Could we have something as "Good Day" for them to use so as to reduce cause of their embarrassment in front of their senior colleagues?

Comment: I'd use _Good morning!_.

Comment: 'Good Day' is rare in Modern English. 'Hello' or 'Hi' is the generic default.

Comment: Good to see you or Nice to see you.

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely use **Good day** any time of the day. If it is 11:30ish AM and not quite 12 PM you can still say "Good morning". Other alternatives that I use any time of the day are "Hello!", a friendly "Hi!" or even just a friendly upper nod, or a usual nod. And people are happy.

Answer (score 0):

We have "Good day".
We also have "Sir" and "Ma'am" said with a nod. The nod is important, as without it, the one word might seem a question. "Doctor" with a nod, also.

If names would be appropriate in a greeting, then Mr., Dr., Ms., followed by the last name, with a nod would be good. First names, if appropriate, the same.

The "nod" greeting resolves any issue with time of day. It can also save time. The worst greeting is no greeting;  the "nod" greeting avoids that.

If the greeted responds with a "Good (Morning , Afternoon, Evening)", the greeter may respond "(Morning, Afternoon, Evening)" followed by a "Sir", Ma'am" or "Doctor" and be finished.

> Doctor (with a nod)
>   Good Afternoon  (responds the Doctor)
>   Afternoon, doctor

Comment: Of course, whatever said must be accompanied with corresponding body-language to positively attach warmth (authenticity). In stead of verbal greeting, we may nod along a smile(if possible) & eye-contact; all three can go as attending strangers  or colleagues at peak hours. Thank you Noah & J. Taylor for your valued response.